# hibernate - table name definition

Tags: java, hibernate

I recently came across the following definition:

```
<class name="X" table="master..[User]" ... />
```

what does the above definition mean?

Comment: are the dots in the code or have you added them?...could you post all (or significant part of) code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mapping declaration for **class X** to the table **User** in the **master** database, probably on SQL Server.

In SQL server you can qualify a table name with a database using double-dot. Square brackets around a name ensure that reserved words or names with spaces can be correctly identified.

[Here's](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping) the reference to the mapping declararation, section 5.1.3